# Reading a javascript variable and add to html iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In the below code I have 2 JavaScript variables long and lat

my challenge is to then being able to append those values to the end of the iframe URL

assistance in changes I need to make to the code below to allow me to achieve the above would be appreciated

The iframe code below  i need to be able to replace the numeric values "-37.718821,145.064612" with the js variables lat long which the code below dynamically determines from the page url

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script>

            function gup(name) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
                var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
                if (results == null)
                    return "";
                else
                    return results[1];
            }
            var latlong = (gup('q'));
            var parts = latlong.split(",");
            var lat = parts[0];
            var long = parts[1];


        </script>



    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="map_display_Page">

            <div data-role="header" id="myheader" data-position="fixed" style="background: #ffffff"></div>
            <div data-role="header" id="myheader" data-position="fixed" style="color: #ffffff; background: #000033;">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
                <h1>Map Location</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <iframe src="maps1.html?q=-37.718821,145.064612" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;"></iframe>  --->          </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="myfooter" style="color: #ffffff; background: #000033;">
                <div class="ui-bar">
                    <a href="sharedialog.html"  data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-theme="a" data-rel="dialog">Share</a>
                    <a href="mailto:info@TrackingCentral.com.au?subject=Iphone App Enquiry" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="a">Contact</a>
                    <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="a" style="float:right;" class="returnTopAction">Return top</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, check it out now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("iframe").attr("src", "maps1.html?q="+ lat +"," + long +");
```

This just changes the src attribute of the `iframe` and replaces it with your variables `lat` and `long`.

Comment: Hi please advise where i place this code, is it in place of the iframe code i have in the landing page (when i do it simply displays the text of the code you have suggested)

if i place it on the index page to load the jquerymobile script when this page loads it generates an error in the web console inspector advising unexpected end of file and when i remove the last " in the code  it then advises unexpected ")"

Comment: @user2134512 you need to place it jut below the ending script tag which is `</script>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("iframe").attr("src","maps1.html?q="+lat+","+long);
});
```

Or

```
$("iframe").src="maps1.html?q="+lat+","+long;
```